# MongoDB query result cursor is unexpectedly empty when used multiple times

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

My code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

    class NewOrders:

        def __init__(self):
            self.client = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
            self.db = self.client['Flipkart']
            self.sale_order = self.db['sale_order'].find({'status':'APPROVED'})

        def getOrderItemId(self):
            oiids = []
            for each in self.sale_order:
                oiids.append(each['orderItemId'])
            return oiids

        def getStatus(self):
            stts = []
            for each in self.sale_order:
                stts.append(each['status'])
            return stts
```

I am trying to call the above two methods from a single class object like:

```
x = NewOrders()
print x.getOrderItemId()
print x.getStatus1()
```

I get a response like:

```
['OD1','OD2','OD3']
[]
```

When i use two different class object i get:

```
['OD1','OD2','OD3']
['APPROVED','APPROVED','APPROVED']
```

Why I am not able to call both via a single object?

Comment: Should be `list(self.db['sale_order'].find({'status':'APPROVED'}))`

Comment: Can you call `x.getOrderItemId()` twice getting the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [find](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) method of a collection returns a [cursor](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor), which can iterate over the results a single time. You can use the [rewind](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.rewind) method to return the cursor to the start again, or you can cache the results of the query in a list, like vaultah suggested.

Comment: Note that all `.rewind()` really does ( in the drivers that acutally still implement it ) is "re-execute" the query associated again. But of course the basic statement is true that cursors are always a "one way trip".